# Matrix to a power

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers

Let $k$ be fixed natural number and let

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}a_1&*&*&...&*\\0&a_2&*&...&*\\0&0&a_3&...&*\\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\0&0&0&...&a_n\end{bmatrix}$$

where $a_i^k=1$ for every natural $i$. The $a_i$ are pairwise distinct and $*$ denotes a random complex number. My question is:

> Is it true that $A^k=E$?

I've tried for some matrices and its seems to be true, but I have no idea how to start solving this. Thanks for any idea!

Comment: It isn't true. What examples did you try? A simple $2\times 2$ counterexample is easy to find.

Comment: Could you more elaborate on what is $E$?

Comment: @JackyChong Not so uncommon notation for the identity matrix.

Comment: ok, my bad, i didnt mention that a_i != a_j for i != j. Sry for that :(

Comment: Ok, i will try now

Comment: @ctst i've tried for  a=c=0, b=1 and got 2+2e^(-2*i*pi/5)+2e^(2*i*pi/5)+2e^(4*i*pi/5)(1+e^(2*i*pi/5)) , which, as wolfram says, is equal to 0 :(

Comment: @ctst also i cant understand why we need n=k to use cailey-hamilton here :( Our matrix is n x n anyway, but i cant get how can that theorem help here :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is (since all the $a_j=e^{2i m_j\pi/k}$ are parwaise distinct) $$\chi_A(X)=\prod_{j=1}^n (X-a_j)$$ which furthermore divides $$(X^k-1) =\prod_{j=1}^k (X-e^{2i j\pi/k}) $$ (this is the product of all $k$th unitroots, hence the equation). Since Cayley-Hamilton says that $\chi_A(A)=0$ and hence even $(A^k-1)=0$. I think you can take it from here :-) (I notate your $E$ as $1$, just in case you wonder)

Answer (score 6):

The eigenvalues of a triangular matrix are its diagonal entries, and any matrix with distinct eigenvalues is diagonalizable. Therefore, by an appropriate change of basis you may assume that all entries of $ A $ off the main diagonal are zero. Now, the result should be obvious...